# NL - iterating all edges of a graph in log space

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs

Given a turing machine which has logrtmic space, and consists of an input tape and a working tape, Is it possible to iterate all egdes of an input graph? I know the answer is probably NO, because clique and other similer NP problems  belongs to NP and not to NL. Unfortunately, I can't find a satisfying and clear explanation to that fact. Can some one make it more clear for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's absolutely no problem to iterate over all edges in a graph in logspace (even deterministic logspace!). The details depend on how the graph is encoded. For example, if the graph is encoded as an adjacency matrix, then you can simply go over all pairs of vertices.

However, this doesn't give an NL algorithm for clique. The problem is that you need to iterate on $k$-tuples of vertices, for non-constant $k$. This is something you cannot do in logspace.

NP is sometimes described in terms of witnesses. However, the "official" definitions is using nondeterministic Turing machines, which are allowed to have more than one correct move at any given point in time. The class of languages accepted by nondeterministic polytime Turing machines coincides with the class of languages which are given a polynomial size witness and can verify it in polynomial time. Unfortunately, there is no such alternative description for nondeterministic logspace Turing machines.

Comment: Oh, I see. But if a graph G, and a witness set of vertices U, are available on the input tape and we just need to verify U, is it not possible to just Iterate on all pairs of vertices (in U) and check (in G) that all corresponding edges exists? And therefore - verify a clique in logspace?

Comment: A nondeterministic Turing machine can make nondeterministic moves – in other words, make a guess – and then verify it. But it doesn't get a witness as an input. It turns out that NP can be *equivalently* defined in terms of witnesses, but this equivalence breaks for NL.

Comment: Now I got it. I was mistakenly thinking the "witnesses definition" can also be applied to NL. Thank you!

Comment: I think you can have a witness based definition for NL. The only difference would be that you have read-only one-way access to the witness tape. (Since we're talking about logspace machines, we have to be careful about the access model to polynomial-sized strings.)

Comment: Right, good point.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the edges of a graph in logarithmic space, since all that is required in order to do so is a counter up to the number of edges. Note that the hardness of clique and other hard problems in NP does not lie in simple iteration, but in detecting different structures in your input which are not apparent (e.g. a clique of a large enough size).

Additionally, languages decidable by Turing machines which are not able to read the entire input are decidable in constant time, so not being able to iterate over the entire input is not interesting in the standard Turing machine model (as opposed to random access).